# How to set a restriction for each phone/user on my app?

Tags: java, android, mobile, restrictions

I'm starting to build an app where people vote certain stuff just by clicking on happy/sad faces (kind of like grading it). The thing is that I dont want to make a log-in nor registration for my app (the reason is a long story). So is there any way that I can limit people's vote to 2 per day? Every phone/user could only vote twice a day, and that count will reset after 24h from the first vote.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have tow options:
Limit the number of votes on the device, by saving the number of votes into persistant storage on the device with a timestamp and act accordingly.

Or (more secure,  but also more difficult)

Track the installations as described here [identifying app installation](http://android-developers.blogspot.ch/2011/03/identifying-app-installations.html)
And send the id with every request and validate on the server side.